# How do you recover lost files on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: data-recovery

I was using terminal commands to uninstall ProtonVPN. Now I discovered that I wiped out all my files including pictures, videos, documents, etc. I have tried to recover using testdisk but nothing was restored. What can I do?

Comment: What was the exact command you used?

Comment: Are you using the ZFS file system? If so, you may be able to restore a recent snapshot …

Comment: @vanadium that question is closed as a dupe. Probably best to close as a duplicate of the final dupe target: [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/q/3883)

Comment: @terdon, that link looks really helpful. Most of the options are a few years old though - do you (or anyone else) know if they are all still effective / which is best to try first / any other more recent options? Thanks.

Comment: @Will I doubt things would have changed. Most of the options are basic disk recovery tools that depend on you not having overwritten the locations on your drives where the files used to be. All are cumbersome and time consuming and none are guaranteed to bring your files back. I'm afraid the only real answer is "restore from backup" :(